# How can I assign a mimetype to a file extension?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mime-types

Sometimes my .tsx files are assigned the mimetype `application/javascript`. But I'd like my .tsx files to always have the mimetype `text/plain`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should share one of these `*.tsx` file

Comment: Seconding Gilles ' request: it's not clear to us what a .[tsx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSX_(disambiguation)) contains. (Probably clear to you, but please rest assured, the world is big enough to avoid guesswork here) Also: Who's the party doing that assignment? I.e., how or where do you see that? In your folder manager, using `file` on the command line, using a library in Python, or somewhere else?

Comment: And... What is the point ? I mean the BIG picture behind...

Comment: Seeing that you tagged [tag:arch-linux], have you checked the (even applicable outside Arch Linux) [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_MIME_Applications#mimeapps.list)?